# Count values in one column based on the categories of other column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm working on the following dataset:

[image: dataset]

and I want to count each value in the LearnCode column for each Age category, I've tried doing it using Groupby method but didn't manage to get it correctly, can anyone help on how to do it?

Comment: Yes exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a groupby on two columns

```
results = df.groupby(by=['Age', 'LearnCode']).count()
```

This outputs a count for each `['Age', 'LearnCode']` pair

Comment: thank you, it works but how can i get the count of each (LearnCode) Category now?